# Change in internal energy for the heating and vaporisation of water

Tags: thermodynamics

> What is the value of change in internal energy at $\pu{1atm}$ in the process $$\ce{H2O(l,$323\ \mathrm K$)->H2O(g,$423\ \mathrm K$)}$$
>   given $C_{\mathrm m,V}(\ce{H2O,l})=\pu{75.0 J K^{-1} mol^{-1}}$ and $C_{\mathrm m,p}(\ce{H2O,g})=\pu{33.314 J K^{-1} mol^{-1}}$
>
> a. $\pu{42.91 kJ/mol}$
>   b. $\pu{43086 kJ/mol}$
>   c. $\pu{42.6 kJ/mol}$
>   d. $\pu{49.6 kJ/mol}$

I tried to use the First Law here. For chemical reaction I found $\Delta n_\mathrm g$ to be $1$ and the heat of the reaction $\Delta H$ is given as $\pu{40.7 kJ mol-1}$. However, I am not able to use the specific heat data given in the question. What am I doing wrong here?

I am getting stuck in phase change reactions, particularly in using $C_p$ and $C_V$ here. I know the First Law will work, but how do we use $C_p$ and $C_V$ in such reactions?

Comment: @GENESECT I got you are started by replacing the image. That should help to format the other parts of the post. Also, option d was cut off in your image.

Comment: It seems like you might have to use the density of water and the ideal gas law to approximate the change in volume as water goes from the liquid to vapor state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this problem is to first determine the  change in enthalpy for this constant pressure process.  Do you think you can do that?  Then determine the change in PV between the initial and final states.

Comment: But why is heat of the reaction equal to change in enthslpy here... I don't understand the logic

Comment: Are you talking about the overall change, or the enthalpy change for vaporization?

Comment: You are aware that, for a constant pressure process, Q is equal to Delta H, right?

Comment: I got that. It's a constant pressure process so we can use ncp∆T.Will this be overall heat

Comment: No.  Heat is being added during vaporization at constant temperature and pressure, and this portion of the heat is equal to the enthalpy change for that step in the process.

Comment: Can you tell me heat in this whole reaction how to calculate it

Comment: To do this, you need to know the heat of vaporization of water at one temperature, in this case 373K = 100 C would be appropriate.  Do you know the heat of vaporization of water at 100C?  And, are you familiar with Hess' law?

Comment: Don't know about hess law but we are going to. Learn it

Comment: I know hess law now. I know the enthalpy of vaporisation but wouldn't the enthalpy be the heat added to water from 50 C to 150 C... Why are we just including the heat of vaporisation?

Comment: What do you get for the enthalpy change between the initial and final states, and how did you calculate it?  Please show the details.

Comment: I divided the reactions in three parts, prior to boiling, at boiling and after boiling. I cakculated the enthalpy seperately. I used the density of steam and calculated the enthalpy at vapourisation

Comment: The enthalpy of vaporization is tabulated, and does not require a calculation.

Comment: Sorry... I used it to calculate internal energy at boiling point

Comment: ∆H=∆U+∆PV.i know ∆H here

Comment: But I am confused on what to take at ∆V

Comment: For $\Delta (PV)$, you use the pressure times the specific volume of the vapor in the final state and subtract the pressure times the specific volume of the liquid in the initial state.